# Getting " 'NoneType' object is not iterable" error for iterlinks

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, lxml

I am encountering " 'NoneType' object is not iterable" error for iterlinks for my below code. Can someone please help?

```
from lxml import html
source=urllib.request.urlopen("http://google.com").read()
tree=html.document_fromstring(source)
for i in tree.iterlinks:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Well `i` is `None` at some point.

Comment: Is `iterlinks` a property or a function? From my brief research, it looks like you should be calling it, though that won't necessarily solve the problem. See [here](https://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html)

Comment: The code you posted would give the error `TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable` with no mention of `NoneType`. Please don't lie when asking for help, you are only going to take more time to receive a correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`tree.iterlinks()`](https://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#working-with-links) in your `for` loop:

```
for i in tree.iterlinks():
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
(<Element style at 0x7f9e6e41ca48>, None, '/images/nav_logo229.png', 1054)
(<Element link at 0x7f9e6e406db8>, 'href', '/images/branding/product/ico/googleg_lodp.ico', 0)
...
```

Comment: I don't think that this is the issue of the OP. If this was the problem the error would read: `TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable` and would not mention `NoneType`. It seems the Op is lying about their actual code. They are probably correctly calling `iterlinks` (and the missing parenthesis are a typo) but they assume that the second value of the returned tuple is never `None`.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta Good catch. Looks like OP has not posted the correct code